# type does not take parameters Scala

Tags: scala, constructor

I have case class State and want to extend Variable class from it; but in Variable class only need value in constructor. Where can I put `run` function?

```
case class State[S, +A](run: S => (A, S)) {
//.....has `map` function
  def map[B, X >: State[S, B]](f: A => B): X =
    State(state => {
      val (a, s2) = run(state)
      (f(a), s2)
    })
}

class Variable[+A](value: A) extends State[A, A] { // ERROR

  def get: Variable[A] =
    map(x => x)
  def set(newValue: A): Variable[A] =
    map(_ => newValue)
}
```

**UPDATE**
I've changed to something like this:

```
class Variable[+A](value: A, run: A => (A, A)) extends State[A, A](run) {
  def get: Variable[A] =
    map(x => x) // ERROR HERE
  def set(newValue: A): State[A, A] =
    map(_ => newValue)
}
object Variable {
  def create[A](value: A): Variable[A] = new Variable[A](value, x => (x, x))
}
```

But I've gotten error:

*type mismatch;  found   : com.libs.State[A,A]  required: com.libs.Variable[A]  Variable.scala  /scala/src/com/libs line 4  Scala Problem*

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot define a `Variable` using `map`, since `map` defines a `State` which is only a super-type of `Variable`. How can your program know how to set the additional information of your subclass, using only `map`?

However, if you define `type Variable[+A] = State[A, A]`, so that it is not a subclass but an alias for the same class, you will have  some variance errors, since `State`  is invariant in its type parameter `S`, so `Variable` must be too.